# Recovering Windows 8 using only a Recovery partition

Tags: windows-8, system-restore, asus-laptop, recovery-partition

I have an Asus N56JR, where the Windows 8 recovery information is stored on a partition called Recovery. Normally, one does a system restore by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> on startup, which will boot a recovery environment where Windows can be reinstalled.

However, after installing Linux, I am no longer to boot into Recovery at all. My Windows partitions were wiped, but I left the Recovery partition intact. Is there any alternative way I could boot it?

I do not have access to any kind of Windows installation or other recovery discs. The only think I can work with is the recovery partition.

Comment: Why don't you just download a installation disk from Microsoft all you need is your license key.

Comment: It'll depend if Asus put a working key on the sticker... or if the license is on the firmware... firmware license should be easy and will just need a disk, as you say, but if the sticker has a non-working key (as it's pre-activated) then they'll have other option but to buy recovery disks from Asus.

Comment: @Ramhound - there is no license key sticker on recent ASUS models, including this one. The key is embedded in the firmware.

Comment: @BigChris - did I understand it correctly from your comment that I can use a regular install if my key is embedded in the firmware?

Comment: Use the disk for precisely the same version that was originally on the device (i.e. If it had Windows 8 then you must use a standard disk, not "Pro" disk) and, yes, it should read the firmware and activate. Because the key is on the firmware and you haven't changed any hardware then when Windows goes to activate it should provide the same data to Microsoft and Microsoft will recognise the device and activate.

Comment: @chrsva - You still have a license.  There are multiple tools that will provide your key from the embedded information.  But the installation disk will also automatically detect your license.  If your actions deleted your recovery option you don't have no other choice except to download an installation disk or create a recovery disk within Windows I suppose.